# Store temporary pointer before releasing to avoid referencing

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and have been stumped on this code in `RefCountObject.h` from Angle project

```cpp
    void set(const ContextType *context, ObjectType *newObject)
    {
        // addRef first in case newObject == mObject and this is the last reference to it.
        if (newObject != nullptr)
        {
            reinterpret_cast<RefCountObject<ContextType, ErrorType> *>(newObject)->addRef();
        }

        // Store the old pointer in a temporary so we can set the pointer before calling release.
        // Otherwise the object could still be referenced when its destructor is called.
        ObjectType *oldObject = mObject;
        mObject               = newObject;
        if (oldObject != nullptr)
        {
            reinterpret_cast<RefCountObject<ContextType, ErrorType> *>(oldObject)->release(context);
        }
    }
```

I don't understand the second comment, what the temporary pointer helps to avoid referencing an object when its destructor is called? Is it a best practice?

Comment: Hard to say with so little context, but I guess the worry is that, if `mObject` is an instance variable, you would be wise to ensure that it's always pointing to something that actually still exists.  But a better question might be, why all the casts?

Comment: My guess is that since you don't know what code can be in objects destructor you can't be sure that `this` object wouldn't be accessed somehow and you need to put it to "valid" state before such call.

Answer (score 1):

I think the purpose of this is to ensure that `mObjects` is always valid (i.e. it always point to a valid/existing object).

A rationale behind that would be in the case if something in the program is likely to consume/read the value pointed by `mObject` at anytime (a thread or whatever), we must guarantee that it will never happen when the variable is deleted and before it is reassigned.

This would explain the need to keep the variable always valid and to release it after having already reassigned it (thus requiring to get a temporary to delay the deletion of the old/replaced object).